# React native trackplayer not on background

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

I want react-native-trackplayer NOT to work in background mode. So when i close the app i want react-native-trackplayer to STOP.

I have already configured this for android

```
android: {
              appKilledPlaybackBehavior: StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification
          },
```

I haven't tested it but the docs say it would work. I am now looking for a solution on IOS.

This is my code, i tried something with IOSBackgroundMode but i can't get it to work.

```
import TrackPlayer ,{ Capability, AppKilledPlaybackBehavior, StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification, IOSCategory  } from 'react-native-track-player';
import { PlaybackService } from './service';

registerRootComponent(App);

TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() => PlaybackService);
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({
      iosCategoryMode: IOSCategory.Ambient
    }).then(() => {
      TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
          android: {
              appKilledPlaybackBehavior: StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification
          },
          progressUpdateEventInterval: 2000,
          color: "#ff35cf07",
          // Media controls capabilities
          capabilities: [
              Capability.Play,
              Capability.Pause,
              Capability.SkipToNext,
              Capability.SkipToPrevious,
              Capability.Stop,
            ],
            compactCapabilities: [
              Capability.Play,
              Capability.Pause,
              Capability.SkipToNext,
              Capability.SkipToPrevious,
              Capability.Stop,
            ]
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('ERROR SETUP PLAYER', err));
```

This is what is in my service.js file (PlaybackService)

```
import TrackPlayer, {Event, IOSCategory} from 'react-native-track-player';

export const PlaybackService = async () => {
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.PlaybackError, async (code, message) => {
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemotePlay, async () => {
        await TrackPlayer.play()
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemotePause, async () => {
        await TrackPlayer.pause()
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemoteNext, async () => await TrackPlayer.skipToNext());
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemotePrevious, async () => await TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious());
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemoteSeek, (position) => TrackPlayer.seekTo(position));

}
```

react-native-trackplayer keeps playing in background, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you checked on IOS device? Because it should stop once you kill the app. It is the default behaviour. For android you should add appKilledPlaybackBehavior: StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification. But for IOS it's the default behaviour.